# MSACCESS returning NULL values where textbox = "blank"

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a search query that returns values from textboxes. I want to add the functionality to return all rows where Comments is null or empty.

I have tried editing the SQL to accept "blank" in the textbox and return all the rows where comments is null. I just added the OR to the original portion of the code.

```
(((IIf(Nz([Forms]![Home]![CHOOSE_COMMENTS],"")="","",[WCL_DATABASE].[COMMENTS] Like [Forms]![Home]![CHOOSE_COMMENTS]))<>False)
```

or

```
((IIf(Nz([Forms]![Home]![CHOOSE_COMMENTS],"")="Blank","",[WCL_DATABASE].[COMMENTS] Like ""))<>False) )`
```

When I search "blank", I receive no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Null` and an empty string (`""`) are two different values.

I'm guessing you'll want to use something like this:

```
select * from YourTable where 
([Forms]![Home]![CHOOSE_COMMENTS] = "Blank" and [WCL_DATABASE].[COMMENTS] is null) or
([Forms]![Home]![CHOOSE_COMMENTS] is null) or
([WCL_DATABASE].[COMMENTS] like [Forms]![Home]![CHOOSE_COMMENTS])
```

This means:

- If the user types "Blank" then records with no comments are returned.
- If the user leaves the comments field blank, then all records are returned (no filter).
- Else the comments are wildcard matched with the user entry.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `NZ` on both sides of `LIKE` equation to match on a filler item such as *MISSING*. This will handle the`NULL` cases. To handle empty (zero-length or whitespace only strings), use `NZ` on one side of equation since form controls with no value render as `NULL`. With both approaches you avoid the `IIF` call.

Below should cover `NULL` cases, non-missing cases, and empty-string cases.

```
WHERE NZ([WCL_DATABASE].[COMMENTS], 'MISSING') 
          LIKE '*' & NZ([Forms]![Home]![CHOOSE_COMMENTS], 'MISSING') & '*'
   OR TRIM([WCL_DATABASE].[COMMENTS]) = NZ([Forms]![Home]![CHOOSE_COMMENTS], '')
```